# Passport.js authenticate to Gmail API leads to GooglePlusAPIError

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, passport.js, google-plus, gmail-api

I use Passport.js to authenticate with Google. I define the following scope:

```
passport.authenticate('google', {
  scope: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
  ],
})
```

So, I just would like to access the Gmail API.

Now, Google responds with:

```
GooglePlusAPIError: Insufficient Permission
```

I get it working when I add the Google+ API to my projekt via the Google API dashboard and by adding the following scope to my passport.authenticate call:

```
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
```

But why do I need the Google+ API when the only thing I would like to do is access Gmail?

I also found this website: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server where they set these scopes:

```
SCOPES = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
  # Add other requested scopes.
]
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers,
Niels

**Edit:**

I just researched on my Google API dashboard and found the screen below. So, are these scopes mandatory?

[image: screenshot of my Google API dashboard]

**Edit 2**

The context is an Express.js app. The whole call looks like:

```
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
  scope: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
  ],
}));

router.get('/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {
  failureRedirect: '/',
}), (req, res) => {
  req.session.token = req.user.token;
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: Hi again! I edited my question with further details about my Google API dashboard. Hope it helps? :)

Comment: Which method are you calling that is giving you the error?

Comment: Hi @DaImTo thanks for your response. I put more context in my question (see the section "Edit 2"). So, the context is an Express.js app. I surf to "/google" to authenticate and Google redirects to "/google/callback". This is where the error occures.